# updating related models from parent model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to create a related model via the parent model using the uRL of the parent model

Parent : Applications
Related : Applicants
This is the below relationship

applications --> hasMany -- > applicants ( foreignkey : application
id )
applicants --> BelongsTo --> applications (foreignkey : applicationid  )

I want to do an upsert on both the models togther using the url of the parent model
PATCH /api/applications

Below is the `applications.js` file

```
    module.exports = function(Application) 
    {
    Application.afterRemote('upsert', function(ctx, instance, next){
      var response ={};
      response.id = ctx.result.id;

    var applicants = ctx.req.body.applicants || undefined;
    Application.getApp(function (err, app) { 
        var resp = { "applicants" :[]};
        if (applicants){
        for (var i=0; i<applicants.length ; i++)
        {
            applicants[i].application_id = ctx.result.id;
            app.models.Applicants.upsert(applicants[i], function (err, result) 
            {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (!result) {
                    var err = new Error("Insert into Applicant failed");
                    err.statusCode = 500;
                    next(err);
                }
                 // This prints the result in the console.
                console.log('***** In APP' + JSON.stringify(result));
                resp.applicants.push(result);
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(applicants));
        }
        // This still results in a empty array
        response.applicants = resp.applicants;
        ctx.result = response;
    }
    });
    next();
});
```

How can I fetch the result of the upsert to the applicants model and then send it back in the application response for the api.

Thanks

Comment: I don't excatly get what you do want to achieve, but remember your *'app.models.Applicants.upsert(...'* runs *asynchronous* that is why *response.applicants* will always result in an empty array in your case.

Comment: is there another way i can synchronously call the upsert method for the related model. Once the applicant is created/modified i want to send the response back to the client with the application details and the applicant details 

example :

{ "application_id" : 1, "applicants" : [{"applicant_id" : 1,"application_id" : 1, "name" : "abc", "country" : "IN" .......}]}        or is there a better way to handle this kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do. There is certainly a better way thought but it might be a good start.

```
'use strict';

var app = require('../../server/server');
var models = app.models;
var Applicants;
app.on('started', function () {
    Applicants = models.Applicants;
});

module.exports = function (Application)
{
    Application.afterRemote('upsert', function (ctx, instance, next) {
        var response = {};
        response.id = ctx.result.id;
        var applicants = ctx.req.body.applicants || undefined;

        if (applicants) {
            var resp = {"applicants": []};
            var count = 0;
            for (var i = 0, applicantsLength = applicants.length; i < applicantsLength; i++) {
                applicants[i].application_id = ctx.result.id;
                Applicants.upsert(applicants[i], function (err, result) {
                    if (err)
                        return next(err);
                    if (!result) {
                        var err = new Error("Insert into Applicant failed");
                        err.statusCode = 500;
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    resp.applicants.push(result);
                    count++;
                    if (count === applicantsLength) {
                        response.applicants = resp.applicants;
                        ctx.result = response;
                        next();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
};
```

If this is not working, you should look for the **'[before save](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#before-save)'** hook.

Comment: Thanks this is working. However, i did look at the before save hook,   i cant see how i can use the before save hook to do the above.

Comment: Like I said earlier, I didn't understand exactly what was your goal, so maybe 'before save' isn't usefull for you. Please check the answer as accepted if it helped, thanks.